# Python-Excel: How to write lines of a row to an existing excel file?

Tags: python, excel

I have searched the site but I could not find anything related to the following question.

I have an existing spreadsheet that I am going to pull data from on a daily basis, the information in the spreadsheet will change everyday.

What I want to do is create a file that tracks certain information from this cell, I want it to pull the data from the spreadsheet and write it to another spreadsheet. The adding of the data to a new spreadsheet should not overwrite the existing data.I would really appreciate the help on this. See code below:

```
import os
import openpyxl
import xlrd

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Test_shorts.xlsx','r')

sheet = wb.active

rows = sheet.max_row
col = sheet.max_column



rows = rows+1

print rows
new =[]
for x in range (2, 3):
   for y in range(1,10):
        z= sheet.cell(row=x,column=y).value
        new.append(z)
print(new)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy the whole worksheet, you can use `copy_worksheet()` function directly. It will create a copy of your active worksheet.

I don't know your data, but I am sure you can finish it by yourself. Hope this may help

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file_name = "Test_shorts.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(file_name)

sheet = wb.active
target = wb.copy_worksheet(sheet)

# you can code to append new data here
new = wb.get_sheet_by_name(target.title) # to get copied sheet

for x in range (2, 3):
    for y in range(1,10):
        print(x,y)
        z= sheet.cell(row=x,column=y).value
        new.append(z)

wb.save(file_name)
```

as commented, a loop of cells are required so I altered your code a little.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file_name = "Test_shorts.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(file_name)

current_sheet = wb.active
new_sheet = wb.create_sheet("New", 1)

for row in current_sheet.rows:
    col = 0  # set the column to 0 when 1 row ends
    for cell in row:
        col += 1  # cell.column will return 'ABC's so I defined col for the column
        new_sheet.cell(cell.row, col, cell.value)

wb.save(file_name)
```

Comment: Thank you. but what I want to do is copy row by row into the new excel sheet by rows not the entire workbook.